# Writing structured logs with Serilog

Tags: c#, .net, serilog, structured-logging

I tried the following log with Serilog:

```
this.logger.Debug("Incoming metrics data {ClientId}", new { clientid = 54732 });
```

Serilog produced this output:

```
Incoming metrics data "{ clientid = 54732 }"
```

Serilog being a structured logger I've expected it to produce something like this:

```
Incoming metrics data {ClientId}, {clientId: 54732}
```

Am I doing something wrong or am I understanding Serilog/structured-logging wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Two things; first, to serialize a structure like this you need to use the *structure-capturing operator* `@`:

```
this.logger.Debug("Incoming metrics data {@Client}", new { ClientId = 54732 });
```

This will capture the individual properties of the object passed in, so the event in the rewritten example will have a `Client` property with `ClientId` sub-property.

This will give you output like:

```
Incoming metrics data {"ClientId": 54732}
```

(Assuming you are using the latest Serilog console sink with the default template; other configurations may not print the embedded data JSON-style.)

The second consideration is that the full structure of the event isn't shown in Serilog's text output - it's the "human-friendly" face of Serilog. If you want to record structure, you might plug in `CompactJsonFormatter` like so (again assuming the console sink):

```
.WriteTo.Console(new CompactJsonFormatter())
```

This works for files etc., too - details at https://github.com/serilog/serilog-formatting-compact.